# How to SUM and Subtract from different table columns in MSACCESS with criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

This question has been partly answered before but I would like to add a question. The code that I have gotten from here is running but I would like to  get the only records that have iif(TblLoan.FutureValue is null, 0, TblLoan.FutureValue) - 
    iif(Payment.TotalPaid is null, 0, Payment.TotalPaid) = 0 or less. in other words, only the records that have 0 or less Balance.

```
    SELECT TblLoan.LoanID, TblCustomer.LastName, Payment.TotalPaid AS Payments, iif(TblLoan.FutureValue is null, 0, TblLoan.FutureValue) - 
    iif(Payment.TotalPaid is null, 0, Payment.TotalPaid) AS Balance
FROM (TblLoan LEFT JOIN (SELECT LoanID,  sum(TotalAmount) as TotalPaid 
        FROM TblPayment group by LoanID
        )  AS Payment ON Payment.LoanID = TblLoan.LoanID) LEFT JOIN TblCustomer ON TblLoan.CustomerID = TblCustomer.CustID;
```

I know that there should be a where clause but I couldn't figure out where to put it since placing WHERE Balance =< 0 at the end of the statement doesn't seem to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-use the expression itself in the `where`clause, not the alias "Balance". Note that you can use the [`Nz`function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) instead of `iif`here:

```
SELECT      TblLoan.LoanID,
            TblCustomer.LastName,
            Payment.TotalPaid AS Payments, 
            Nz(TblLoan.FutureValue) - Nz(Payment.TotalPaid) AS Balance
FROM        TblLoan 
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT  LoanID,
                        sum(TotalAmount) as TotalPaid 
                FROM    TblPayment group by LoanID
            )  AS Payment 
        ON  Payment.LoanID = TblLoan.LoanID 
LEFT JOIN   TblCustomer ON TblLoan.CustomerID = TblCustomer.CustID
WHERE       Nz(TblLoan.FutureValue) - Nz(Payment.TotalPaid) <= 0;
```

Comment: Is it okay to use Nz if I am working on the actual ms access itself?

Comment: Sure, `Nz` is in fact a `VBA` function, so supported within MS Access itself. If you would be looking for a syntax that is supported in other databases as well, then you could use [`COALESCE(..., 0)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249645.aspx) ...

Comment: Thank you for your time trincot. You have given me a great sql arsenal. Good day.